# `babel-loader` dependency error when `rake assets:precompile` in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I've inherited a Rails application and I'm trying to get it to build manually in `production`

The application uses

- `webpacker-3.5.5` ruby gem to manage JavaScript assets
- `webpack v3.12.0`
- `sprockets` gem to manage traditional CSS / Image assets

As part of the webpacker gem config, it uses `babel-loader` on JSX/React assets particularly. I'm not quite sure what this does, but I'm guessing it's some sort of pre-processor?

```
module.exports = {
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [{
    loader: "babel-loader",
    options: {
      cacheDirectory: true,
      // Use .babelrc - not webpack config JS - to define all options
      babelrc: true
    }
  }]
}
```

When I try to run `rake assets:precompile` on the production server, it errors on the step where it tries to build assets with `webpack`

```
> rake assets:precompile
yarn install v1.17.3
warning package.json: No license field
warning delly@1.0.0: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 1.18s.
Webpacker is installed  
Using /app/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
Compiling…
Compilation failed:

Hash: 27785324c8b2ba6004dd
Version: webpack 3.12.0
Time: 119ms
        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
manifest.json  2 bytes          [emitted]

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/app'

ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'babel-loader' in '/app'
```

This does not happen in `development` locally, only `production`.

Any idea why this would be erroring? Is `babel-loader` required in production or can I remove it from production entirely?

Here is my `package.json` that defines installation of the package:

```
{
  "name": "delly",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/.bin/jest --no-cache --config spec/javascript/jest.config.js",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk node_modules/.bin/jest --no-cache --config spec/javascript/jest.config.js --colors --verbose"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.8.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint": "^4.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.6.1",
    "i18n-js": "^3.2.2",
    "jest": "^24.8.0",
    "jest-dom": "^3.4.0",
    "js-yaml": "^3.13.1",
    "react-testing-library": "^7.0.1",
    "stylelint": "^9.3.0",
    "stylelint-config-rational-order": "^0.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.11.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.5.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "core-js": "3",
    "html-react-parser": "^0.4.6",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.2.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.1",
    "rails-erb-loader": "^5.4.1",
    "react": "^16.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.0.0",
    "react-on-rails": "^11.3.0",
    "react-toggle-switch": "^3.0.4",
    "react-transition-group": "1.x",
    "react_ujs": "^2.4.4"
  }
}
```

a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run `rake assets:precompile` in production mode, it also runs `webpack` using production mode, in this case, only packages set in `dependencies` are loaded, if you review `packages.json`, `babel-loader` is set in `devDependencies`.\

The solution? move `babel-loader` to `dependencies`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know what that section was for. What about all the other `babel-*` items and some even start in `@babel-*`. Do I move those too? In general im not sure what's needed in the babel dependency tree

Comment: I would move most of the packages to `dependencies` except for `eslint`, `jest` and `webpack-dev-server`